# Is 何か an adverb?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

> 何かいいことがあったか？
>
> 何か一言を言ってください

In sentences like these, is 何か an adverb? I have read that [counters such as 一つ are adverbs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Japanese/Grammar/Counters) when used in sentences like りんごを一つ食べた. Is it possible that 何か is functioning like an adverb similar to how 一つ is functioning like an adverb in that sentence.

Comment: see [なにか➋](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/164507/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8B/)

Comment: ^ ❶ではないでしょうか。「どことなく。なんだか。」とも「なぜ…か。どうして…か。」とも言い換えられないので。

Answer (score 2):

何か can be used to mean 'something', which can also be an adverb; or 'anything', which can be used to describe the extent/magnitude, and is an adverb in that case.

> 何かいいことがあったか？ - What's the good news? / Did something good happen?
>
> 何か一言を言ってください - Please say a few words.

How about

> りんごを一つ食べた, as opposed to 一つのりんごを食べた?

The former's 一つ functions as an adverb while the latter is just a noun.

So to answer your question: Yes, it is an adverb in those sentences.

Comment: 語が『副詞的に機能する』ことと、『副詞である』ことは別の事象として捉える必要があるかと思います。

Comment: @Yuu 「何か一言**を**言ってください」--> 普通は「何か一言言ってください」となるのではないかと思うのですが。

Comment: @choco, yep, I agree. 一言 is usually used adverbially too.

Answer (score 2):

In the sentences 何かいいことがあったか？ and 何か一言言ってください, which can be translated respectively:

> Was there something good (good news) for you? - Here ‘something’ is used as a subject.
>
> Would you please say something (a few words?) – Here ‘something’ is used as an object.

I think '何か' functions as a pronoun rather than an adverb.

The usage of '何か' here is different from '一つ' in 'りんごを一つ食べた,' where '一つ' corresponds to 'an' or 'one' of 'an (one) apple.'